# redux-form is not showing its all props values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, redux, redux-form

***i want to  use all eventHandler of redux-form as show in sameple output image but its not coming as a props so i facing  undefine error now what i can do to solve the issue***

**i have imported reducers in index.js file of src folder and create store**

**package.json**

```
 {
  "name": "reactjs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
    "redux-form": "^8.3.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
 import { reducer } from 'redux-form';
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

export default combineReducers({
    reducer

})
```

**TouristRegistration.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { reduxForm, Field } from "redux-form";
    import { Button } from "@material-ui/core"
    import RegistrationField from "./ReaperComponent"

    class TutiorsRegistrationForm extends Component {
    handlenextpage = () => {

        this.props.nextPage()
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <Field
                    type="text"
                    name="FirstName"
                    component={RegistrationField}
                />
                <Button
                    color="primary"
                    variant="contained"
                    type="submit"
                >Next
                </Button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

const validate = (value) => {
    const errors = {}
    if (!value.FirstName) {
        errors.FirstName = "Required"
    }
    console.log("error " + JSON.stringify(errors));




    return errors;

}

export default reduxForm({
    validate: validate,
    form: 'TutiorsRegistrationForm'

})(TutiorsRegistrationForm);
```

**RegistrationField.js**

```
 import React from 'react';
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core"

const ReaperComponent = (props) => {

    console.log("props " + JSON.stringify(props));
    return (

        <TextField />

    );
}

export default ReaperComponent;
```

**output**
[of instructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6yJT.png)

**output in my case**

```
props {"input":{"name":"FirstName","value":""},"meta":{"active":false,"asyncValidating":false,"autofilled":false,"dirty":false,"form":"TutiorsRegistrationForm","invalid":false,"pristine":true,"submitting":false,"submitFailed":false,"touched":false,"valid":true,"visited":false}}
```

Comment: Can you let us know what exactly is undefined?

Comment: all properties i want to use for example props.input.onBlur  props.input.onChange props.input.onDragStart and some others

Comment: @muhammadusman i think you need to first set the reducer correctly with key `form`:
https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/docs/gettingstarted.md/#step-1-of-4-form-reducer

`import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'`
`const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // ...your other reducers here
  // you have to pass formReducer under 'form' key,
  // for custom keys look up the docs for 'getFormState'
  form: formReducer
})`